# Where can I find a red bandana?

Tags: golf-story

Over by the disk golf area in Wellworn Grove ([north of the swan lake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Tlql.jpg)), there is a balding man who asks if you can find him something resembling a red bandana.

> I'm feeling a little self-conscious. Think you could... get me a **red bandana**? Or something that **resembles one**.

I've searched high and low, but I haven't been able to find one. I did find an employee by the course entrance who was wearing a red bandanna, but talking to him didn't seem to do anything.

**Where can I find a red bandanna for the balding man in Wellworn Grove?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Wellworn Grove you will find a woman who wants her son to get out of the water.

The woman is next to a hole, in which you'll find a red flag. That red flag "*resembles a red bandana*". Normally, if you interact with a hole, you get to remove the flag or insert it. This hole is different in that it doesn't allow you to remove the flag.

In order to retrieve the flag, you need to whack it with a golf ball. One way to do it, is to press <kbd>Y</kbd> to place a ball on the ground, then hit the ball with any of your golf clubs. Throwing the ball (press <kbd>X</kbd>) towards the flagpole also works.

If done correctly, the flag will slide down the pole. You can then interact with it to retrieve it. All that's left to do is talk with the self-conscious guy to hand over the "bandana" to him.

Comment: Confirming that you can throw a golf ball at the flag to knock it down. (From north of the hole)